# pig latin in c++, some bugs for "flower" and "rhythm"

Tags: c++, apache-pig, flower

My code works fine except for "Flower" and "Rhythm". The output turns out this way: "Owerfiay", "Ythrmreay"; where "i" and "e" are i-cap and e-cap. I tried checking the ASCII table in case I went wrong somewhere but I can't find these two in the table. My knowledge in c++ is limited so when I tried reading some of the existing threads here and anywhere else, I couldn't keep up with them.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void toPigLatin(char *i){
    int k,m;
    char *n;
    n = i;
    printf("Pig Latin version: ");
    if(*i=='A'||*i=='a'||*i=='E'||*i=='e'||*i=='I'||*i=='i'||
           *i=='O'||*i=='o'||*i=='U'||*i=='u'){
        k = 0;
        while(*i!='\n'){
            printf("%c",*i);
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        printf("way");
    }else{
        k = 1;
        i++;
        while(*i!='\0'){
            if(*i=='A'||*i=='a'||*i=='E'||*i=='e'||*i=='I'||*i=='i'||
                *i=='O'||*i=='o'||*i=='U'||*i=='u'||*i=='Y'||*i=='y'){
                break;
            }
            k++;
            i++;
        }
        i = n + k;
        char *r;
        r = n;
        while(*i!='\0'){
            if(*n>=65&&*n<=90)
                printf("%c",*i-32);
            else
                printf("%c",*i);
            i++;
            n++;
        }
        i = r;
        m = 0;
        while (m!=k){
            if(*r>=65&&*r<=90)
                printf("%c",*i+32);
            else
                printf("%c",*i);
            m++;
            i++;
        }
        printf("ay");
    }
}

int main(){
    char arr[16],*i,check[16];
    i = check;
    printf("Enter a word: ");
    scanf("%s",arr);
    while(1){
        strcpy(check,arr);
        if(strcmp(check,"exit")==0){
            break;
        }
        else{
            printf("\n\n");
            toPigLatin(arr);
            printf("\n\nEnter a word: ");
            scanf(" %s",arr);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The ASCII codes 65 and 90 correspondes to `A` and `Z`, so you could write your conditions as `if ( *r >= 'A' && *r <= 'Z' )`. Your code is in pure C, BTW.

Comment: In 2017 this code looks so strange as trying to get fire by friction...

Comment: You should give a list of words for which the system works as well as the two for which it doesn't. Also, please explain what you mean by 'where "i" and "e" are i-cap and e-cap'.

Comment: @Bob__ -- instead of building in a dependency on ASCII, use `isupper`; it works for the character encoding that the system is using.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(*r>=65&&*r<=90)
    printf("%c",*i+32);
```

This should be checking `*i`, not `*r`.

`*r` is the first letter in the user's word, which is F and R respectively. Since the *first* letter is a capital letter, your code is trying to convert the *current* letter to from uppercase to lowercase.

Your program needs to be checking the current letter instead of the first letter.

However, that said, there's a much easier way to convert a letter to lowercase. You could just use `tolower` from `<ctype.h>`:

```
printf("%c", tolower(*i));
```

This will work even if the letter is already lowercase (it doesn't change lowercase letters).

Comment: Thank you. I looked again, and I added r++ in the while loop. It's fixed now.